# DDD/NHibernate Use of Aggregate root and impact on web design - ex. Editing children of aggregate root

Tags: nhibernate, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

Hopefully, this fictitious example will illustrate my problem:

Suppose you are writing a system which tracks complaints for a software product, as well as many other attributes about the product.  In this case the SoftwareProduct is our aggregate root and Complaints are entities that only can exist as a child of the product.  In other words, if the software product is removed from the system, so shall the complaints.

In the system, there is a dashboard like web page which displays many different aspects of a single SoftwareProduct.  One section in the dashboard, displays a list of Complaints in a grid like fashion, showing only some very high level information for each complaint.  When an admin type user chooses one of these complaints, they are directed to an edit screen which allows them to edit the detail of a single Complaint.

The question is: what is the best way for the edit screen to retrieve the single Complaint, so that it can be displayed for editing purposes?  Keep in mind we have already established the SoftwareProduct as an aggregate root, therefore direct access to a Complaint should not be allowed.  Also, the system is using NHibernate, so eager loading is an option, but my understanding is that even if a single Complaint is eager loaded via the SoftwareProduct, as soon as the Complaints collection is accessed the rest of the collection is loaded.  So, how do you get the single Complaint through the SoftwareProduct without incurring the overhead of loading the entire Complaints collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using NH for another business context but similar entity relationships like yours. I do not understand why do you say:

> Keep in mind we have already
>   established the SoftwareProduct as an
>   aggregate root, therefore direct
>   access to a Complaint should not be
>   allowed

I have this in mine, `Article` and `Publisher` entities, if `Publisher` cease to exist, so do all the dependent `Artcle` entities. I allow myself to have direct access to the `Article` collections of each `Publisher` and individual entities. In the DB/Mapping of the `Article` class, `Publisher` is one of the members and cannot accept `Null`.

Care to elaborate the difference between yours and mine?

Sorry this is not a direct answer but too long to be added as a comment.

Comment: I am definitely not a DDD expert, but my understanding is that one of the main concepts of aggregate root is that the child entities should only be manipulated through the root.  I could be misunderstanding something, but I have seen this rule stated many places.  This link discusses the concept of aggregate roots as well.  
http://dddstepbystep.com/wikis/ddd/blogged-aggregates-and-aggregate-roots.aspx
I think are situations are the same, so you would use an Article Repository to retrieve the specific article, which then would have a Publisher as well?

Comment: @pbrophy: Yes, I do retrieve a specific article in my app. In your case, if SoftwareProduct is a HUGE entity with many other memebrs, you can add specific projections/transformers so that you do not load the entire entity, just those that you need.

Comment: So, when you return the article, do you edit items via the article or the publisher.  In other words, do you say 

Publisher.Articles[0].Title = "New Title"  
PublisherRepository.Save(Publisher)
            OR
Article.Title = "New Title"
ArticleRepository.Save(Article)

Comment: @pbrophy: Yes I use `Article.Title = "New Title"` and then `ArticleDAL.Update(Article)`

Answer (score 5):

This gets a bit into semantics and religiosity, but within the context of editing a complaint, the complaint is the root object. When you are editing a complaint, the parent object (software product) is unimportant. It is obviously an entity with a unique identity. Therefore you would would have a service/repository devoted to saving the updated complaint, etc.

Also, i think you're being a bit too negative. Complaints? How about "Comments"? Or "ConstructiveCriticisms"?

Answer (score 1):

@Josh,

I don't agree with what you are saying even though I have noticed some people design their "Web" applications this way just for the sake of performance, and not based on the domain model itself.

I'm not a DDD expert either, but I'm sure you have read the traditional Order and OrderItem example. All DDD books say OrderItem belongs to the Order aggregate with Order being the aggregate root.

Based on what you are saying, OrderItem doesn't belong to Order aggregate anymore since the user may want to directly edit an OrderItem with Order being unimportant (just like editing a Complaing with its parents Software Product being unimportant). And you know if this approach is followed, none of the Order invariants could be enforced, which are extremely important when it comes to e-commerce systems.

Anyone has any better approaches?

Mosh

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

Aggregates are used for the purpose of consistency. For example, if adding/modifying/deleting a child object from a parent (aggregate root) causes an invariant to break, then you need an aggregate there.

However, in your problem, I believe SoftwareProduct and Compliant belong to two separate aggregates, each being the root of their own aggregates. You don't need to load the SoftwareProject and all N Complaints assigned to it, just to add a new Complaint. To me, it doesn't seem that you have any business rules to be evaluated when adding a new Complaint.

So, in summary, create 2 different Repositories: SoftwareProductRepository and ComplaintRepository.

Also, when you delete a SoftwareProduct, you can use database relationships to cascade deletes and remove the associated Complaints. This should be done in your database for the purpose of data integrity. You don't need to control that in your Domain Model, unless you had other invariants apart from deleting linked objects.

Hope this helps,

Mosh

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mosh. Each ones of these two entities has its own aggregate root. Let me to explain it in the real life. suppose that a company has developed a software. There are some bug in this software, that made you annoy. you are going to go to the company and aware them from this problem. this company gives you a form to be filled by you.

This form has a field - section - indicates to the software name and description. additionally, it has some parts for your complaint. Is this form the same as the software manual? No. It is a form related to the software. It is not the software. Does this form has any ID? yes. It has. In other words, you can call the company in the next day and ask the operator about your letter of complaint. It is obvious that the operator will ask you about the Id.

This evidence shows that this form has its own entity and it could not be confused with the software itself. Any relation between two different entity does not mean one of them belongs to the other.